# ssis package continuted to execute in datafactory after termination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

I ran an ssis package in IntegrationRuntime on data factory.
The package is hosted on an azure sql database.

Its a very basic data  movement from source to sql database table.

I killed off the ssis execution about half way through its run, but the table is still getting rows inserted. This occurred for about 5 minutes after the ssis package was killed within sql server.

is this expected behavior?

Comment: Have you tried running this Package from SQL Agent Job or somewhere else besides ADF and stop the package to see if this happens as well?  if the package is in the middle of executing a long Data Flow task, you must wait until the Data Flow task completes. This is to preserve data integrity and to prevent inconsistent states. The only option here is to kill the process via SQL

Comment: yes, if i run the package from within sql server, when i stop it, it stops. It seems like there is delay with datafactory between stopping the package using SSMS and the package actually stopping.